# Calling a bash command with -c and piped string for awk

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, awk

If I run the following command from the command prompt, it works as expected: -

```
ps -eo pid,command | grep -v bash | grep syslogd | awk '{print $1}'
```

The output is just the pid of the syslogd process. According to the man pages for bash, using the -c argument allows passing a string of commands. So, I tried this: -

```
/bin/bash -c "ps -eo pid,command | grep -v bash | grep syslogd | awk '{print $1}'"
```

Instead of printing just the pid of the syslogd process, the path to syslogd is also printed: -

```
 19 /usr/sbin/syslogd
```

Can someone explain why this is and if it is possible to call the command with bash this way, so that it acts the same as when calling the commands directly and only print the pid of the process?

Comment: As an aside, the proper way to write that is `ps -eo pid,command | awk '!/bash/ && /syslogd/ {print $1}'`. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: @tripleee great name(!) and Thanks ;O)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$1` is being interpreted by the outside shell because it's in double quotes. You'll need to escape it with a backslash.

```
/bin/bash -c "ps -eo pid,command | grep -v bash | grep syslogd | awk '{print \$1}'"
```

By the way, on Linux you can replace all of this with `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep syslogd
25855
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
pidof syslogd
```

Comment: It's not available on OSX, but more interesting is that on my CentOS server, it states 'command not found', though there are man pages for the command.